# java hex data in string

Tags: java, string, hex

I have read a PDF file using PDFBOX in JAVA and have converted the data to text and have saved in a string.  I have found that a lot of the text data is surrounded by X'C2A0'.  For instance:

```
X'436C756233AC2A04469616D6F6E64C2A0'       Club:__Diamond__
```

__ is X'C2A0'

I want to search for "Club:__, then parse between the 2 __ for "Diamond".  I have tried something like:

```
String TAG = "\\xC2A0";                     // Tag in PDF

int pos = text.indexOf(TAG, positionInText);
```

but I never get any hits.  How do I specify TAG?

EDIT:

Maybe some clarification is needed.  I used PDFBOX as such:

```
   public void toText() throws IOException
   {
       this.pdfStripper = null;
       this.pdDoc = null;
       this.cosDoc = null;

       file = new File(filePath);
       parser = new PDFParser(new RandomAccessFile(file,"r"));      // update for PDFBox V 2.0

       parser.parse();
       cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
       pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
       pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
       pdDoc.getNumberOfPages();
       pdfStripper.setStartPage(1);
       pdfStripper.setEndPage(10);

       // reading text from page 1 to 10
       // if you want to get text from full pdf file use this code
       // pdfStripper.setEndPage(pdDoc.getNumberOfPages());

       text = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
```

text is a field defined as String.  This text String is what I amd trying to parse.

Comment: Confusing question. What's `\\xC2A0`? Can you post an actual example?

Comment: Why not TAG="Club" ?

Comment: The hex is wrong, the `33` should only be one `3`. If you convert the hex to bytes, then decode using UTF-8, you get `Club:_Diamond_`, where the two underscores are `C2A0` (UTF-8) aka ['NO-BREAK SPACE' (U+00A0)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm). It's a 2-byte UTF-8 encoding of the single NBSP character (`A0`).

Comment: Is the string above literal.. i.e. String data = "X'436C756233AC2A04469616D6F6E64C2A0'"... or is this from a hexdump / debugger tool?

Comment: @Andreas one 3 is correct, my misstake, miss typed.  Everything you are saying sounds correct.  How do I code my TAG for this?  String data is hand typed from a hexdump. I can search for "Club", but mainly I want to parse between two x'C2A0'.

Comment: When you *"converted the data to text"*, what text did you end up with? Did you correctly convert using UTF-8? If you did, you search for `"\u00A0"`, because that is the *single* character in your text that you got from the *two* bytes `C2 A0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not completely clear from your question if the string you are searching is hex-encoded itself or is a normal character string that in the file contains 2-byte sequences with the character values `0xc2 0xa0`.

Assuming the latter case, in the file the sequence `0xc2a0` is the UTF-8 encoding for the Unicode code-point `0xA0`, which is the non-breaking space that corresponds to the `&nbsp;` entity in HTML.

If the file contains these two-byte sequences, then when read into your Java string (assuming you used the UTF-8 encoding to interpret the byte stream), then each of these sequences will become a single `0xA0` in your string.

You should be able to write a regular expression to find data delimited by pairs of these.

Comment: Try searching for `\xA0`

Answer (score 0):

@Jim Garrison your answer got me searching.  I still do not understand UTF-8 encoding.  Your last 2 paragraphs were right on.  I guess PDFBOX is using UTF-8 to read the PDF file.  I used the following:

```
private final String TAG = "\u00A0";                    // Tag &nbsp X'C2A0'
```

to find and parse data between two x'C2A0' tags.